# RingtoneManager Cursor Not Returning Selected Ringtone Details

Tags: android

I have a `DialogFragment` that pops up a custom ringtone selector. However, it doesn't get the proper `Ringtone` after selecting one and clicking OK. Any idea what is wrong below?

The dialog is created by this

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rm = new RingtoneManager(getActivity());
        ringtones = rm.getCursor();

        int selected = -1;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.ringtone);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(ringtones,
                selected,
                ringtones.getColumnName(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX),
                mChoiceListener);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
        return builder.create();

    }

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mChoiceListener =
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                ringtones.moveToPosition(position);
            }

    };
```

When the OK button is selected, it is captured by

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Log.d("DayPickerFragment", "onClick");
        switch(which) {
            case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialog.cancel();
                break;

            case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                Uri uri = rm.getRingtoneUri(ringtones.getPosition());
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), uri);

                /*** etc ***/

                /*** returned ringtone doesn't match what was selected ***/
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Is this caused by the `rm.getRingtoneUri(position)` method not corresponding to the *ringtones* cursor? If so, how do you get a real `Uri` of the selected item?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it doesn't work. I'm guessing I'm not understanding something about the `Cursor` object.

However, here is what ended up with, using a private variable to move it around

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rm = new RingtoneManager(getActivity());
        ringtones = rm.getCursor();

        int selected = -1;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.ringtone);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(ringtones,
                selected,
                ringtones.getColumnName(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX),
                this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
        return builder.create();
    }

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                dialog.cancel();
                break;

            case Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();

                Uri uri2 = rm.getRingtoneUri(mPosition);
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), uri2);
                /*** Use ringtone as needed ***/
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;

            default: // dialog click
                ringtones.moveToPosition(position);
                mPosition = position;

                Uri uri = rm.getRingtoneUri(mPosition);
                mp.reset();
                try {
                    mp.setDataSource(getActivity(), uri);
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

I'm doing a few extra things like passing in a Ringtone and set it as the selected if it's found, but this is the basic idea.